# How can I use an F# type with generics in Silverlight 4 and XAML?

Tags: silverlight, generics, xaml, f#

Take the F# following code:

```
type Blah<'T>(objects : 'T array) as this = // whatever
```

When I try to use that type in a XAML document, there is no type associated with the generic parameter, and it's ugly. I think the compiler complains, too:

```
<ns:Blah foo="bar"/>
```

So, I try to alias the type like so (at the bottom of my Blah.fs file):

```
type StuffBlah = Blah<Stuff>
```

Then when I use it in the same way in my XAML document, the type is not found to exist:

```
<ns:StuffBlah foo="bar"/>
```

Why is that? Is there a cleaner, more elegant way to do this? I'm still getting the hang of Silverlight, XAML, and F#, so any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know anything about F#, but current XAML spec (which is XAML 2006) does not support generics at all. XAML 2009 does, but it's not in general use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the `StuffBlah` version doesn't work is that particular piece of F# syntax creates a type alias only for the F# project vs. creating an actual type.  Since the name is not visible at the IL level as an actual type it is not accessible to Silverlight or XAML in general.

One way to work around this is to create `StuffBlah` as a first class type which derives from `Stuff<'T>`.  Not ideal at all but it will work.